# null pointer assignment error.!

Tags: c, nullpointerexception, dijkstra

Following is the code for a Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm. The code works fine on small inputs, but i need it for a 2d array size of 200. So I used dynamic memory allocation. Still it gives a null pointer assignment error. Can any one help me to find an alternative way to read an 2 dimensional array for large size.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>


void dij(int n,int v,int **c,int *d)
{
    int i,u,count,w,f[300];
    int min;

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        f[i]=0;d[i]=c[v][i];
    }

    f[v]=1,d[v]=1;

    count=2;

    while(count<=n)
    {
        min=1000000;
        for(w=1;w<=n;w++)
            if((d[w]<min)&&!f[w])
            {
                min=d[w];u=w;
            }
        f[u]=1;
        count++;

        for(w=1;w<=n;w++)
            if(((d[u]+c[u][w])<d[w])&&!f[w])
                d[w]=d[u]+c[u][w];
    }

}


int main()
{
    int v=1,n=4,i,j,k,len;
    char str[20];
    int **c,*d,val;

    d=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    c=(int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        c[i]=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
            c[i][j]=0;
    for(k=0;k<=n;k++)
    {
        do
        {
            scanf("%s",&str);
            len=strlen(str);
            if(len>3)
            {
                sscanf(str,"%d,%d",&j,&val);
                c[k][j]=val;
            }
            else break;
        }
        while(1);
    }

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
            if(c[i][j]==0)
                c[i][j]=1000000;
        }

    printf("enter the source\n");

    scanf("%d",&v);

    dij(n,v,c,d);

    printf("shortest path from\n");

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        if(i!=v)
            printf("%d -> %d=%d\n",v,i,d[i]);
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
```

array indices start from zero.

Comment: .. and the condition/test is usually just "less" `<`, not "less-or-equal" `<=`

Comment: @Levon, yes, that's the logical consequence of start being `0` and length being `n` ;-)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker Yes, I know. And I wasn't criticizing you, it just seemed like an appropriate statement to tag on to yours (and since it was missing I provided it :)

Comment: @Levon, I didn't criticize your comment either! I agreed with you! ;)

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık, I didn't even try to read the whole code, I went straight to memory allocation and once you invoke the undefined, anything can happen.

Comment: @Michael Krelin. Yes you are right. Unhandled boundaries can do anything.

Answer (score 0):

f is [300], did you try 298 299 300 301 and 302 ? all same or 300,301,302 are error?

in the function dij(), max value of i is n, when you set n bigger than 300, it gives error

```
 int i,u,count,w,f[300];  // f[300]<---------constant size
 int min;


  for(i=1;i<=n;i++)

  {
     f[i]=0;d[i]=c[v][i];// here i goes to n, while f[] is f[300]

   }
```